# Use free() for float** inside an struct (two allocations) C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I and my study college are trying to implement a CNN on a redpitaya (sensor combo) and therefore have a limited/ no real debugging options (send some info via UDP and LEDs).
We are having issues with getting the `free()` to work.
The issue is that we have to use structs and have an undefined amount of incoming features. We want to allocate memory for the error and other variables in the struct (seems to work so far). But if we try to free the allocated memory using `free()` the program crashes.
I am not sure how to correctly pass the argument(?) that is stored inside `name_t.error[i]` to `free()`.
We tried several combinations of `&`, `*` and `[]` but none of them worked.
We are no IT-students so thats a little over our capabilities.

```
#define a
//global
struct {
    ...
    float** error;
    ...
} name_t;
name_t var;

main()

init(name_t* f_var, int s1, int s2)
{
    //s1 and s2 not used in the example
    ...
    f_var->error = (float**)malloc(a*sizeof(float));
    ...
    for(){
        f_var->error[i]=(float*)malloc(b*sizeof(float));
        ...
    }

}
//free() ?
free_func(name_t* f_var)
{
    for()
    {
        free(f_var->error[i]);
        ...
    }
    free(f_var->error);
}
//no debugging possible!
```

Minimal Exmample

```
#define a 2

//global
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct {
    int i;
    float** error;

} name_t;
name_t var;
int init(name_t* f_var, int s1, int s2);
int free_func(name_t* f_var);
int main()
{
    int x;
    x = init(&var, 1,1);
    free_func(&var);
    return 0;
}

int init(name_t* f_var, int s1, int s2)
{
    //s1 and s2 not used in the example
    f_var->error = (float**)malloc(a*sizeof(float));
//b an array for the layersize which differs for each layer
    for(int i=0; i<a;i++){
        f_var->error[i]=(float*)malloc(b[i]*sizeof(float)); 
    }
    for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<b;k++)
        {
            f_var->error[j][k]=((float)rand() / RAND_MAX - 0.5);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//free() ?
int free_func(name_t* f_var)
{
    for(int i=0; i<b;i++)
    {
        free(f_var->error[i]);
        if (f_var->error[i]!=NULL)return -1;
    }
    free(f_var->error);
    //if (f_var->error!=NULL)return -1; not needed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How are you calling `init` and `free_func`?

Comment: @MikeCAT It is called at the start of a measurement thread and the free is called via a UDP command. So creating a minimal example is not that easy.

Comment: There are more debugging options available. Remote gdb or eclipse - there used to be an article how to set those up, but the whole wiki appears to be MIA. Or you can enable coredumps, download the dump and look at it in a debugger. If you don't have enough space for a coredump, it seems to support NFS as well. (then the question becomes how to work with core dumps on Linux which I'm sure has plenty of answers somewhere)

Comment: `f_var->error = (float**)malloc(a*sizeof(float));` certainly looks wrong.  If `sizeof(float)` happens to be the same as `sizeof(float *)`, it will be okay.  You can avoid this error by using the idiom `f_var->error = malloc(a * sizeof *f_var->error)`. (Compute size of object instead of size of type, and don't cast the return value from malloc.)

Comment: `(float)rand() / RAND_MAX - 0.5`  You might want to use `drand48()` that gives a `double` vlaue.

Comment: what is the purpose of `if (f_var->error[i]!=NULL)return -1;` in `free_func()`?

Comment: @tstanisl its meant to be used as an error code

Comment: @MeroStud_notIT, `free()` cannot fail if correctly used. And it *will not* change `f_var->error[i]`. The current code will return after releasing  `f_var->error[0]` resulting in memory leak.

Comment: @tstanisl this seems to be the case it's exactly the point at which the crash occurs. This is one of the first times using alloc/malloc, so I dont really understand on how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one error:

```
f_var->error = (float**)malloc(a*sizeof(float));
```

It should be

```
f_var->error = (float**)malloc(a*sizeof(float*));
```

If `sizeof(float*)` is 8 then only a half of required memory would be allocated causing crashes when accessing the other half.

A few hints:

- don't cast result of malloc()
- use `sizeof *XXX` where `XXX` is assigned variable, this will help when type of `f_var->error` is changed

```
f_var->error = malloc(a * sizeof *f_var->error);
```

Comment: Is there a difference in the size of a float and the size of float*? Or do I misunderstand it completely?

Comment: @MeroStud_notIT, `float` is a floating point number, usually encoded on 32bit (4 bytes). `float*` is a pointer, a variable that contains an address in the memory. It usually consists of 8 bytes on 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

You are making your memory allocation and deallocation slower, bigger, and more complex by using an array of pointers data structure instead of an array of arrays.  That's not itself causing your issue, but the more complex code it requires does leave more room for errors.

You are casting the return value of `malloc()`.  This is not necessary in C, and it potentially obscures errors.  Do not do this.  In fact, any cast for other than arithmetic purposes has some code smell.  Nevertheless, this is not responsible for your problem either.

You are not checking for allocation failure.  This could be related to your issue, but that would more likely induce a failure in `init()` than in `free_func()`.

Your top-level allocation for `f_var->error` may allocate insufficient space.  This ...

> ```
>     f_var->error = (float**)malloc(a*sizeof(float));
> ```

... allocates enough space for `a` objects the size of a `float`, but you need space for that many `float *`.  On many systems, pointers are larger than `float`s.  This could explain the failure you observe. You can avoid this kind of error by expressing the needed size in terms of the object receiving the pointer:

```
    f_var->error = malloc(a * sizeof(*f_var->error));
```

Of course, that's also resilient against changes to the type of the receiving variable.

Your `free_func` assumes that `free()` will somehow alter the value of the object presented as its argument.  It can't and doesn't.  In C, all function arguments are passed by value, so `free()` could not change the value of its argument even if it wanted to.  You must not use the value afterward unless it was null to begin with, and in particular, you cannot expect it to be null unless it was null before.  If you want to make it null then you need to do that yourself.  This issue will cause your particular `free_func` to terminate early, without freeing everything.  That likely creates a memory leak, which could be related to the failure.

---

Supposing that in the full code your `b` is indeed a macro expanding to a constant expression, I recommend this instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define b 4
// ...
typedef struct {
    int i;
    float (*error)[b]; // array of arrays style
} name_t;

// ...

int init(name_t* f_var, int s1, int s2) {
    // only one malloc needed
    f_var->error = malloc(a * sizeof(*fvar->error));
    if (!f_var->error) return 1;  // malloc failed

    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < b; k++) {
            f_var->error[j][k] = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX - 0.5);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int free_func(name_t* f_var) {
    // only one free needed
    free(f_var->error);
    fvar->error = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So to clarify we have b Layers each layer has an individual unknown size. If I understand your code correctly it's the opposite. 
In the actual code we have the allocation check left it out for simplicity.

Comment: @MeroStud_notIT, the code presented here declares `name_t.fvar_error` as a pointer to an array of `b` floats.  The `init` function allocates space for `a` such arrays.  The result is that `fvar_error` can be indexed exactly as the original version can be -- the same range of valid indexes in each position -- and it has the same contiguity properties for elements with the same first index (that is, each row is contiguous, as in your case).

Comment: Additionally, however, the whole group of rows is allocated as one block, and you need only the one pointer, not `a + 1` of them.  This is the dynamic allocation variation on a 2D array.

Comment: OK I see but in our case is we need to allocate memory for an known amount (a) of arrays but the length (b) of these arrays differs. eg. the first array has 10 floats the second 100 and the third 60 something like this. english is not my native language so sorry if I misunderstand your answers.

Comment: In that case, @MeroStud_notIT, the question grossly misrepresents your situation, in that the example presented is not representative of the actual problem code.  Please do not waste our time.

Comment: Dude thats just not ok! I am a Robotic student not a highly trained IT guy ok I adapted the things to the question as soon as i see the mistake and try to make it more precise. This is a level of coding far beyond my skill level how should I know how to ask for things I don't fully understand? I don't try to waste your time Im trying to 1) Understand and learn and 2) solve an issue I have. and btw my first comment to your question i stated my problem so pleas read carefully before you answer!